# Using .indexOf() in an if statement in java

Tags: java

I need to use an indexof method but terminal is telling me that it needs a variable but it gets a value.  Can you guys explain how I fix this?

This is what I came up with by myself.

```
char a = 'a';
    if (s.indexOf(a, s.length()) == 61)
        System.out.println(" Your string contains the letter 'a' at index position: " + s.indexOf(97));
    else
        System.out.println(" Your string does not contain the letter 'a'");
```

Comment: Can you specify the language you are using?

Comment: The tags you added are all irrelevant. Looks like Java to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java. Method [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) return the first **position** in string `s` that contains the string you pass in the method. It returns -1 if the string is not found.

```
if (s.indexOf("a") >= 0)
        System.out.println(" Your string contains the letter 'a' at index position: " + s.indexOf("a"));
    else
        System.out.println(" Your string does not contain the letter 'a'");
```

Comment: thanks a lot this worked but I don't understand why. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @WeekzSO If it worked, you should accept the answers. It will help others too who might face the same problem.

Comment: @WeekzSO I added a link to the java API and also a brief explanation :)

Comment: @GPRathour i can't accept the answer for another 6 minutes.